# get tuple as arguments from zipWithIndex in scala

Tags: scala

I can pass and use values from tuple like this in **for**

```
for ((v,i) <- in.zipWithIndex) {
        println(s"$i is $v")
      }
```

But in foreach it's used only like

```
in.zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case(v, i) => println(s"$i is $v")
}
```

How can I make *something* like function

```
val f: (Int,Int) => Unit = (v,i) => {println(s"$i is $v")}
```

and then pass it into `.foreach()`. **AND** (it's important just for me) without using pattern matching `case`.

P.S. `.tupled` works only for methods (`def`). not for function defined as `val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to your function needs to be a Tuple.

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3).zipWithIndex                      
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,0), (2,1), (3,2))              

scala> val f = (t: (Int, Int)) => println(s"${t._1} ${t._2}")
f: ((Int, Int)) => Unit = <function1>                        

scala> l.foreach(f)                                          
1 0                                                          
2 1                                                          
3 2
```

Personally I hate the `._1`, `._n` syntax and prefer to pattern match on tuples.

BTW your for comprehension example is also using pattern matching...

Comment: how about without `case` and `._1`? :) I want to get just readable variable names directly. like `(someReadableName, someReadableIndex) <- in.zipWithIndex` but as function

Comment: "BTW your for comprehension example is also using pattern matching..."
in my **for** example?

Comment: zipWithIndex returns a collection of type Tuple2. The variable names of a Tuple2 are _1 and _2. If you want to access the elements of a tuple you can pattern match, explicitly reference each tuple using the _n syntax or if you really want to complicate things use productIterator. Unless you have a very good reason not to I would use pattern matching.

Comment: `(v,i) <- in.zipWithIndex` is where pattern matching is used - It can be used on the LHS of an expression... Another example would be `val (l, r) = (1, 2)`

Comment: I understood. Thanks!